# using a formula across sheets in numbers

Tags: macos, mac, iwork-numbers

I have a numbers spreadsheet and am making a totals page to take the totals from each page, add them together in an overview sheet and was wondering if anyone knew how to create a formula to do t

Comment: You want to total everything on the sheet? And you are using the spreadsheet program, or something else?

Comment: sorry yes numbers is the program I'm using and i have totals on the sheets and then i want an overall total of all of the sheets without having to manually input any changes

Comment: Will this [LINK to tutorial](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/excel2007/excel2007s8p7.html) help ?

Answer (score 5):

Try this on a simple file.

1. Create two sheets. On the first, enter two numbers, and a formula to add them.

   [image: note the formula]
2. On the second sheet, put a number somewhere, then, in another field, type "=", click on the number, click "+", point to the formula in the first sheet. Click.

   [image: you can type in the formula, or use your mouse/pointing device]